# Swift button in button

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, sirishortcuts

I would like to make a button like the Shortcuts app has.
A big button and inside an other small button.
The small button would open a new view and the big button just run a simple print statement for example.

If the solution is a pod i would be more than happy but i think its nothing difficult just im not paying attention :)

I was able to do that with this stuff:

```
func add(secondButton: UIButton, buttonName: UIButton, secondButtonTitle: String, secondIsEnabled: Bool) {
    secondButton.isEnabled = secondIsEnabled
    print(secondIsEnabled)
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        secondButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemFill
        secondButton.setTitle(secondButtonTitle, for: .normal)
        if buttonName.isEnabled {
            buttonName.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
            buttonName.tintColor = .systemGray4
        } else {
            buttonName.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemOrange
            buttonName.tintColor = .systemGray2
        }
    }else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        // TODO: do
        if buttonName.isEnabled {

        } else {
            buttonName.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
    buttonName.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    view.addSubview(buttonName)

    secondButton.tintColor = .black
    secondButton.frame = CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: 60.0, height: 15.0)
    secondButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    buttonName.addSubview(secondButton)
    buttonName.bringSubviewToFront(secondButton)
}
```

But if the big button is disabled, the small button will disable too

I want to keep the current design which is this [image]
The reason why the last button is red because it is enabled

sorry for the button titles its in Hungarian and i forgot to translate, they are just numbers from 1 to 6

My problem starts here:

There are situations where the big button is disabled.
But I want to keep the smaller button enabled all the time, even if the big button is disabled.
Is this possible?

If im not mistaken my search word for google would be nested buttons but i couldn't really find anything

Comment: Please restructure your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

```
 buttonName.addSubview(secondButton)
```

This is causing your second button to be disabled when the big button is disabled.  Instead, add both to the subview of your main view, then change the layer property so the small/second button appears inside your on top of your big button.

**Solution**:

```
buttonName.layer.zPosition = 0
secondButton.layer.zPosition = 1
view.addSubview(secondButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
buttonName.addSubview(secondButton)
```

Put the second button in front of the first button but not as a subview of the first button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create it as a UIView (buttonsView) containing two buttons

1. Big button covering to whole view (mainButton)
2. Small button with a specific frame (secondaryButton)

So whenever you want to disable the big button, you can specify buttonsView.mainButton.isEnabled = false, so you can be sure that the secondaryButton is not affected by the status of the mainButton